# Halide: How to deal with Expr evaluated as nan or inf?

Tags: halide

I have a 1D `Func` over which I'd like to perform the following: take the sum of a kernel of `n` values, and divide it by the sum of the kernel shifted by 1. Here's the code I have so far:

```
Var x("x");

Func result("result");
RDom r(0, kernel_size);

Expr sum1 = sum(vec_func(x+r));
Expr sum2 = sum(vec_func(x+r+1));           
Expr quotient = sum1 / sum2;

result(x) = quotient;
```

This is an example of the type of calculation which might result in a `NaN` or `Inf`. Ideally I would be able to deal with this in Halide using something like this:

```
Expr safe_calc = select(isnan(quotient) || isinf(quotient), 0, quotient);
result(x) = quotient;
```

Does such a method exist in Halide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Expr Halide::is_nan(Expr)` exists right now, but we are missing `is_finite`. (Added as https://github.com/halide/Halide/issues/2497)

However: be aware that Halide does floating point math in accordance with `-ffast-math` rules, which means it is allowed to optimize the code in ways that assume `NaN/Inf` values can't happen. If it's possible to structure your code in a way to ensure such values aren't possible, you should do so.

Comment: I expect we'll add a target flag to turn off fast-math soon as well.